# Three.js howto realize a reflection effect

Tags: reflection, three.js

I'm trying to reproduce an effect like [lolita.persona.co](http://lolita.persona.co) 
Someone know where i can find something similar/ready for three ?

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can use an effect composer with a postprocessing shader.

I don't want to/can't do all the job for you, so here is just a rough concept with reaction on mouse movement:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x777777);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
textureLoader.setCrossOrigin("anonymous");
var texture = textureLoader.load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg");

scene.background = texture;

// postprocessing
var composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
composer.addPass(new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera));
var effect = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.WaveShader);
effect.uniforms['time'].value = 0;
effect.renderToScreen = true;
composer.addPass(effect);

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  mouse.x = event.clientX / window.innerWidth;
  mouse.y = event.clientY / window.innerHeight;
  effect.uniforms["mouse"].value.copy(mouse);
}, false);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  time += clock.getDelta();
  effect.uniforms["time"].value = time;
  composer.render();
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/shaders/CopyShader.js"></script>
<script>
  THREE.WaveShader = {

    uniforms: {

      "tDiffuse": {
        value: null
      },
      "time": {
        value: 0
      },
      "mouse": {
        value: new THREE.Vector2(.5, .5)
      }

    },

    vertexShader: `

    varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {

   vUv = uv;
   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

  }`,

    fragmentShader: `
    
  uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
    uniform float time;
    uniform vec2 mouse;

  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {
      vec2 uv = vUv;

      //https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldXGz7
     uv.x += (sin((uv.y + (time * 0.07)) * 15.0) * 0.0029) + (sin((uv.y + (time * 0.1)) * 15.0) * 0.002) * (1. + 19. * mouse.x);
      uv.y += (cos((uv.y + (time * 0.04)) * 45.0) * 0.0019) + (cos((uv.y + (time * 0.1)) * 10.0) * 0.002) * (1. + 19. * mouse.y);
      
      uv = fract(uv * vec2(2., 1.));
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(tDiffuse, uv);

  }`

  };
</script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>
```

You can write you own fragment shader to achieve the effect you want.